# Disassembling a simple C++ program

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    cin >> s; 
    if (s == "almafa")
        cout << "ok";
}
```

In gdb I disassembled main and started the program, entered 'testing' as input, and stopped at the comparison 0x0000000000400bb7:

```
   0x0000000000400bab <+53>:    lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400baf <+57>:    mov    $0x400d24,%esi
   0x0000000000400bb4 <+62>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400bb7 <+65>:    callq  0x400c6a <bool std::operator==<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*)>
```

I inspected the esi and rdi registers:

```
(gdb) x/s $esi
0x400d24:   "almafa"
(gdb) x/s $rdi
0x7fffffffddc0: "\320\335\377\377\377\177"
```

What is in the rdi register? I expected it will contain my input.

Comment: In all likelyhood, *rdi* contains a pointer (the machine code equivalent of a reference) to the `s` object. That's the first argument to the `operator==` overload you are invoking. Since you requested a string representation of a pointer value, the debugger decided that those aren't ASCII characters and displays their values in octal instead.

Comment: Consider compiling the source code with `g++ -S -fverbose-asm -O`  and look into the generated `.s` assembler flie

Answer (score 3):

rdi is the pointer to your `std::string` object.

Note that the function call is to an `operator==` that takes a `const char *` parameter.

The `std::string` class defines an `operator==` that takes a `const char *` parameter, and this is what's being invoked here, with rdi pointing to an in-memory representation of the `std::string` object, and with the parameter in esi.

> What is in the rdi register? I expected it will contain my input.

It is not your input. Your input was stored in the `std::string` object, and that's what's being pointed to, here.